# Proving that the sets $A$ and $A\setminus B$ have the same cardinality if $A$ is uncoutnable and $B$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A$ is an uncountable set, and $B$ is a countable subset of $A$, then prove that $|A|=|A\setminus B|$.

I know that to show two sets have the same cardinality, I can show that there is a bijection between them. I would just like a hint in order to start the proof; please refrain from full solutions. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

After considering Asaf's hint, I've gotten the following:

$|B\cup A\setminus B|=|B|+|A\setminus B|=|A|$.

I'm not too sure how to proceed. Can I subtract $|B|$ from both sides like this:

$|A\setminus B|=|A|-|B|$, and conclude that the right side must be infinite as the removal of a countable set $B$ from an uncountable set $A$ cannot make that set $A$ countable, and hence if the right side is uncountable, so is the left side as we know that the sides equal each other?

Comment: Regarding my hint, what do you know about addition of cardinals?

Comment: $|B|+|A\setminus B|=\max\{|B|,|A\setminus B|\}$, so $|B|+|A\setminus B|=|A|\implies |A|=\max\{|B|,|A\setminus B|\}$?

So since we know $|B|$ is countable, this must mean that $|A\setminus B|=|A|$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint then $|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** $A\setminus B$ contains another countable (infinite) subset.